How many chapters are in Nier Reincarnation?
How many story chapters are in Nier Reincarnation? The game just released its final chapter. I just finished chapter 10 and want to know how many chapters I have left to complete before the game shuts down on April 29th. I couldn't find the answer immediately when searching and don't want to accidentally come across spoilers.

According to NieR Re[in]Guide, there are 3 arcs with 31 chapters in total.
Girl
14 chapters:

1. Prologue
2. His body, rust
3. What was lost
4. Two lonely marionettes
5. This violent, fleeting world
6. The distant peak
7. Redemption: black
8. Interval prologue
9. priSOner
10. LIberator
11. A cold and hollow silence
12. The reclutant hero
13. Echoes in the heart
14. Redemption: white

Sun/Moon
10 chapters:

1. The Sun: prologue
2. Binding magick
3. Curse of the rift
4. One vow
5. Moon's intermission
6. Proof of zero
7. One thousand moons
8. One sun
9. Hina
10. Yuzuki

People/World
7 chapters:

1. Opening
2. The beginning of everything
3. Broken children
4. Patched emotions
5. Guidance followed
6. Cherished memories
7. Goodbye


I'm trying to avoid looking at the names of chapters I haven't reached yet. What is the total count of chapters?

@Stevoisiak is it better now?

You don't need to put spoiler tags, just wanted a number of chapters at the top of the answer.
